# How to send a list only text by WhatsApp

Tags: javascript, php, html, whatsapp

Good morning. I have an application that sends specific notifications on WhatsApp. I currently send travel reservation data and that works correctly. What I need now is what I need now is to send a list of data to a user. Let's say I want to send a list like this:

```
Customer code || Order Code

00000563 || 00967

00005531 || 00890

00008239 || 00920

000002315|| 00790
```

Currently I send a Link to an html-js table and it works correctly. I even send more information.

But I would like an orientation to create a list as indicated before or something similar. Since as you will see it is not a table as such, but a minimally ordered data. I have thought about creating it with JavaScript or from the backend, which is an api in PHP. Creating before the text with the data and sending it as a single JSON. I hope someone has done something similar and can guide me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

my understanding is you would like to send a formatted message: like a list, a set of buttons,...

I would recommend you have a look at this package (read under "list message") as it is implementing different messages formats:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@inutil-labs/node-red-whin-whatsapp

You can see these working examples:

- https://youtu.be/8Lj2gJjNJZw
- https://youtu.be/sc21V2TXs8U

I hope it helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33384317)